# iOS - how to get lines under the text in text view like the notes app on the iPhone?

Tags: ios, uitextview

how do I put lines under the text on a textview ?

this is that I did :

```
UIColor *bgColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"line.png"]];
[textView setBackgroundColor:bgColor];
```

but the lines aren't aligned on the bottom of the line.

Answer (score 1):

As I understand you, the actual text you write is not aligned with the stripes on the "notepaper" background?

If so, you need to mess around with the image until you hit the right place.

Answer (score 0):

The easy way: check [this](https://github.com/danielamitay/DALinedTextView)

The hard way: draw the lines manually using Core Text and Core Graphics. Core Text allows you access font metrics, such as line height...